# Which name should I use for a category of pictures: lifeless/still life/?

Tags: meaning

I created a website for my photographs which are organized into three categories: *people*, *nature*, and *lifeless* (see [here](http://photography.andersthorin.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=1&Itemid=114)).

It seems to me *lifeless* could seem derogatory. Is it?

If it is, what would be a better word to use to categorize photographs which are about neither people nor nature?

Comment: I'd just go with "other", in this case.

Comment: @keshlam so you think _lifeless_ does not suit, right?

Comment: Given the other uses of the word, I'd avoid it in this context. Of course the divisions you're making are somewhat arbitrary; what do you do with a picture of a man looking at a computer with a dog next to him?

Comment: @keshlam : sure, my criterion is what matters most in the picture which is of course arbitrary. I'll wait for any possible suggestions to come but will go for _other_ otherwise! TY.

Answer (score 3):

*Lifeless* means something without life, a corpse could be described as being *lifeless*, we also say a *lifeless body*; dolls are said to have *lifeless eyes* although the eyes appear realistic they are expressionless and blank. If you describe a group of photos as being *lifeless* the viewer might interpret this two ways. First, as a metaphor, the subjects are indeed without life, they are non-living things whose existence have been recorded in light (photo). Secondly, and possibly the one you most want to avoid, the photos are dull, expressionless and *dead-looking*.

***Still life*** is probably the term you are looking for. Wikipedia describes it as

> [**Still life**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life) is a work of art depicting mostly inanimate subject matter,
> typically commonplace objects which may be either natural (food,
> flowers, dead animals, plants, rocks, or shells) or **man-made** (drinking
> glasses, books, vases, jewelry, coins, pipes, and so on).
>
> [**Still life Photography**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life_photography)
>
> Still life photography is the depiction of **inanimate subject matter**,
> most typically a small grouping of objects. Still life photography,
> more so than other types of photography, such as landscape or
> portraiture, gives the photographer more leeway in the arrangement of
> design elements within a composition.
>
> Still life photography is a demanding art, one in which the
> photographers are expected to be able to form their work with a
> refined sense of lighting, coupled with compositional skills. The
> still life photographer makes pictures rather than takes them. Knowing
> where to look for propping and surfaces also is a required skill.

As alternative titles to *still life* consider *man-made "life"*; *post-industrial*; or the gloomier *dystopia*.

Comment: I'm now hesitating between _other_ and _man-made life_ since I think not all my pictures can correspond to only one of the following suggestions (I won't detail as it would be out of topic): "still life", "dystopia", "abstract", "dynamic", "technology", "cityscape". Also, I had thought about "inanimate", but prefer the two mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I looked your photos.  Your third category could be termed "abstract", "dynamic", or "technology".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend distinguishing *landscape* (nature with focus on the view) v.s. **cityscape** (which is an "urban" equivalent).

As a general descriptor of your works, you could use "modern" and "contemporary" in addition to `@Theresa`'s diction.